# In Macropy block macro -- how to access kwargs in the context statement

Tags: macropy

In this dummy macropy block:

```
from macropy.core.macros import Macros
macros = Macros()
@macros.block
def noop(tree, *args, **kw):   
  return tree
```

which is invoked as follows:

```
with noop(x=1):
   print ("hello world")
```

how to access the keyword arg (x,1). If arg is scalar, then it provided in the 'args' key of the **kw.